# Regex to match everything."LettersNumbers"."extension" and forum searching tip

Tags: regex, windows, search, explorer

I would need a regex to match my files named "something".Title"numberFrom1to99".mp4 on Windows' File Explorer, my first approach as a regex newbie was something like 
    "*.*.mp4"
, but it didn't work, so i tried 
    "*.Title[1-9][0-9].mp4"
, that also did not work.

I would also like a tip on how to search regex related advices on Stackoverflow archive but also on the web, so that i can be specific, but without having the regex in the searching bar interact.

Thank you!

EDIT
About the second part of the question: in the question itself there is written "..mp4" but i wrote "asterisk"."asterisk".mp4, is there any universal way to write regex on the web without it having effect and without escaping the characters? (in that way the backslash shows inside the regex, and that could be misunderstood)

Comment: surely this is a superuser question?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(.*)\.[A-za-z]+\d+\.mp4
```

See this [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV5fY0/2) to get an explanation on the regex.

Use regex101.com to test your regexs

Comment: Using that ambient i had a different behaviour, i matched everything before ".mp4" with "asterisk"."asterisk". In file explorer, but that didn't work in regex101.

Comment: Also i tried to remove the point before "Title" doing "cmd /c "ren ^[\s\S]*\.Title$ ^[\s\S]*Title$"" Without \ ^ $, And it did nothing, when on regex101 was matching what i wanted.

Comment: I am on Linux right now, so I can´t test this, but maybe windows explorer doesn´t support regex, try using some other program like powergrep that supports regexs.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
^[\s\S]*\.Title[1-9][0-9]?\.mp4$
```

I suggest regexr.com to find many interesting regexes(Favourites tab) and simple tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

About the second part of the question: in the question itself there is written "..mp4" but i wrote "asterisk"."asterisk".mp4, is there any universal way to write regex on the web without it having effect and without escaping the characters? (in that way the backslash shows inside the regex, and that could be misunderstood)

Comment: You should edit your original post and include this part in the question, otherwise it will be hard for other people to see it. As for this question, I believe that to use characters, that are also regex operators, as literals you have to espace them.

Comment: Without special characters, it would not be regex. You should just keep in mind to use \ before: .^$*+?()[{\|-

Comment: Also, the correct way to use the wildcard (dot) with asterisk is: " .* ", whitch means matches any character between zero and unlimited times.